# Dual boot windows 8 and Ubuntu not see partitions 1

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Windows 8 and then installed Ubuntu .The PC directly runs Ubuntu, it does not ask which system should it run.

Ubuntu is the latest version. It runs in too slow; if I open any application. It takes 3 to 5 minutes to open.

My PC configuration is  4GB RAM  ,  320GB HARD DISK.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In order to get dual boot back (selecting between windows and Ubuntu)

Follow 2nd option given in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

For slowness, can you check what processes are running and how much CPU is consumed ? (by typing top in terminal)